# What do we mean by collision prevention when we are writing proxy contract for a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.8.x, contract-upgrading, erc

I am learning to write a proxy contract in `Solidity`.

> What do we mean by collision when writing proxy contract for a smart contract?
>
> > I have some other questions as well , pls refer to comments inside this code snippet.

```sol
contract Proxy {
      // slots to prevent collision ( idk what it actually means ) 
        bytes32 public constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = bytes32(          // slot for implementation contract ( this slot stores address of implementation contract ) 
            uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.implementation")) - 1 // can I write anything instead of eip1967.proxy.implementation here ? What exactly is the meaning of this line ?
        ); 
        
        bytes32 public constant ADMIN_SLOT = bytes32(                   // slot for admin contract ( this slot stores address of admin contract ) 
            uint(keccak256("eip1967.proxy.admin")) - 1 // can I write anything instead of eip1967.proxy.admin here ? What exactly is the meaning of this line ?
        ); 
        );
// rest of the code here 
}

library StorageSlot {

    struct AddressSlot {
        address value;
    } // why is the value stored inside AddressSlot struct and not just simply as normal variable address value ?

    function getAddressSlot(bytes32 slot) internal pure returns (AddressSlot storage r) {
        assembly {
            r.slot := slot
        } // what does this code inside assembly do ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the collision refers to **memory collision**.

**For example:** Your `Proxy` contract has the address of the `Implementation/Logic` contract. And that address is written inside `Proxy` contract's storage.

However, what happens if one of the functions in your `Implementation/Logic` contracts overwrites that memory slot? Suddenly your `Proxy` contract can't call the `Implementation` contract because he lost the address.

That is an example of **memory collision**.

I advise you to watch this tutorial that showcases the memory collision to understand it better: [Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xluCHy_HB-4&t=378s&ab_channel=SmartContractProgrammer)